# Converting HTML with Mathematical Symbols to PDF with Javascript support PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf, dompdf

I have a web page which has mathematical symbols in it which is rendered using JavaScript. I have used ASCII Math plugin and ASCIISVG plugin to create and display mathematical expressions in web page. Now I have a requirement to convert this web page to PDF. I have tried dompdf and fpdf, but both failed since these convertors do not support Javascript.

Is there any way to  achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rely on JavaScript you have two options:

1. Render on the client and capture the generated document content. You can then send that content to the server for rendering to PDF. dompdf does not currently support SVG, so with this method you would have to use another output format or another library (I'm not sure which ones support SVG). The main drawback is that this does require user interaction.
2. Use a headless browser. These are full browser engines compiled into a command line client. These usually support the full web stack (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, SVG). The web content is rendered in memory after which you can export to PDF and image formats. The best I've seen so far is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). The only drawback is that you have to be able to install binaries on your system and execute them.

Comment: Phantomjs trick worked for me. I'm checking a way to implement this in a linux enviroment with PHP.